# Break nested loops

Tags: c#, .net, nested-loops, label

Can someone tell me how to break the main loop when I have nested loops?
Example*:

```
/*Main loop*/
for(int y = 0; y < 100; y+=10)
{
    /*Sub loop*/
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x += 10)
    {
        if(x == 60) 
        { 
            //Break the main loop 
        }
    }
}
```

*This code do nothing, it's just an example

What should I put in the place of the "Break main loop" comment? In java there are labels which I can break (when i set a label to the main loop named "MainLoop" I can write "break MainLoop;"  and it will be valid), but what can I do here?

Thanks in advise!

Comment: if possible, put this inside a separate method that you can just return out of, that will short circuit the loops.

Comment: GOTO!  Hey, wait - where you guys going?  Hello?

Answer (score 19):

`goto`!

I fail to understand this persistent meme which says that `goto` is considered "harmful". When used correctly, it is very powerful, and this is such a case.

Comment: One day when someone hands you three decade-old FORTRAN code that was peppered with poorly written GOTOs, and tells you to fix the bugs, and you discover that it is _impossible_ to refactor, you will understand. The best programmers can do magic with GOTO.  The worst can do great evil.

Comment: The best programmers can use `goto` without causing any grief whatsoever, and create the most efficient code in the process.

Comment: +1, breaking nested loops is one of the few (only?) acceptable uses of goto imo. Much, much cleaner than using a flag.

Comment: @cjrh And that's why he said _Well used, it is very powerful, and this is such a case._. Right tool for the right situation.

Comment: I just don't see why some people here would rather use a flag than a goto in this case.

Answer (score 11):

- refactor so you don't need to exit nested loops in this way.
  Using `return` is often possible by putting the loops into a seperate function.
- use `goto`.
- Use a flag (ugly)

Comment: No one should ever use `goto` in a high-level language.

Comment: IMO flag-break-checkflag-break is even uglier than goto. But of course refactoring is the preferred choice where possible.

Comment: `goto` is perfectly legitimate, and this is the best use for it, it's more efficient than any of the other options presented. No programmer should live by rules such as "never use `goto`", instead you should know **when** to use `goto`.

Comment: @IAbstract This is `exactly` the type of situation where `goto` is the best answer. Stop regurgitating the `never use goto` rubbish you've been taught. Use the right tool in the right situation.

Comment: @Rob: the correct answer is to refactor. I don't like the *flag-break-checkflag-break* option either ...and it's not about regurgitation, it's about correctness.  :)

Answer (score 6):

Use a flag to signal termination:

```
for(int y = 0; y < 100; y+=10)
{
     bool flag = false;
     for(int x = 0; x < 100; x += 10)
     {
        if (x == 56)
        {
           flag = true;
           break;
        }
     }

     if(flag) break;
}
```

Comment: Thats a verbose way to do it. You can just check the flag in the `for` loop conditional.

Comment: Nice thing about this is that it is very easy to understand for other programmers: zero surprise factor.

Comment: @Jon, I don't think it's a clean style to have more than one condition inside a for.

Comment: I prefer goto over this workaround. (Of course only if refactoring is no good choice)

Comment: @cjrh do you actually think so? I, for one, think goto is *much* more obvious here -- not to mention more efficient.

Comment: @fge: tbh, when for-loops require termination earlier than their limits suggest, I suspect that that should be an _exceptional_ condition, if you catch my meaning.  From that point of view, goto and exceptions do exactly the same thing.

Comment: It's done with flags like that in PASCAL .. I thought that c# may have something cleverer like Java did .. but I'll use this ..
I tried the goto statement but it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 6):

Some people would shoot me for suggesting the use of the `goto` statement, but breaking out of multiple loops is one of the places it can be very useful (and efficient):

```
/*Main loop*/
for(int y = 0; y < 100; y+=10)
{
    /*Sub loop*/
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x += 10)
    {
        if(x == 56) 
        { 
            goto MainLoopDone;
        }
    }
}

MainLoopDone:
// carry on here
```

Comment: They're terrible when used by young coders and result in spaghetti code. As a developer you should use the tools available to you, and goto is the most efficient way of getting out of several nested loops.

Comment: I agree with the prior about spaghetti code I always use break or return

Comment: +1 - I'm with you - this is one of the few places where goto makes things better, not worse.  Restructuring to avoid the nested loops would be ideal, but if that's not an option, then `goto` away!

Comment: Hogan's simple solution of an extra boolean variable is nearly just as a efficient, and a lot more maintainable and clear to other programmers.

Comment: I don't see how it's more maintainable. If there were more loops involved you'd have to change more code, also this doesn't require an extra variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? You made need to post an updated version of your code for us to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

often its better to put this into a separate function and then do a 'return'

```
void loop_de_loop()
{
  for(int y = 0; y < 100; y+=10)
  {
      /*Sub loop*/
      for (int x = 0; x < 100; x += 10)
      {
          if(x == 56) 
          { 
              return;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the real nested loops I'm calculating some thing. If I have to pass them to a method it'll be really ugly !

Comment: depends how you do it....often these things get messy because people have lots of variables and haven't encapsulated them into a struct.  Ideally you end up with a lot of functions that work on a struct.  ( simplified OO).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a way to break out of nested loops in C#, but allow me to suggest a workaround.

You could throw the main loop into a function and return out of that function. You can `return false;` to indicate a premature break and `return true;` to indicate that the loop went all the way through, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Flags, as suggested in the comments, are probably the best method:

```
boolean someFlag = true;

for(int y = 0; i < 100 && someFlag; y += 10) {
  for(int x = 0; x < 100 && somFlag; x += 10) {
    if(x == 56)
      someFlag = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's only that short because there is no code after the inner loop and after the if. With that code you need to add two breaks and a check.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Main loop*/
for(int y = 0; y < 100; y+=10)
{
    bool makeMeBreak = false;

    /*Sub loop*/
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x += 10)
    {
        if(x == 56) 
        { 

            //Break the main loop 
            makeMeBreak = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (makeMeBreak) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no good generic answer. The 'right way' depends on the real problem. The best way might be to put the outer loop in a function and then use `return;` to break out of it. It might be `x=100; y=100;`. It might be `done=true;`. Heck, it might even be `goto` (kidding).

Answer (score 0):

Not advisable but you can use `goto`. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx).

```
public class GotoTest1
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int x = 200, y = 4;
        int count = 0;
        string[,] array = new string[x, y];

        // Initialize the array:
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)

            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                array[i, j] = (++count).ToString();

        // Read input:
        Console.Write("Enter the number to search for: ");

        // Input a string:
        string myNumber = Console.ReadLine();

        // Search:
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                if (array[i, j].Equals(myNumber))
                {
                    goto Found;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The number {0} was not found.", myNumber);
        goto Finish;

    Found:
        Console.WriteLine("The number {0} is found.", myNumber);

    Finish:
        Console.WriteLine("End of search.");


        // Keep the console open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
/*
Sample Input: 44

Sample Output
Enter the number to search for: 44
The number 44 is found.
End of search.
*/
```

Not advised because it makes the flow harder to understand. Other option of course is to set some flag in the inner loop and check it in the outer loop, I discounted that as it's obvious and assume you know it anyway.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since, as you've mentioned, there's no labels on the `break` command, you could do something like this:

```
/*Main loop*/
bool fFound;
for(int y = 0; y < 100 && !fFound; y+=10)
{
    /*Sub loop*/
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x += 10)
    {
        if(x == 56) 
        { 
            //Break the main loop 
            fFound = true;
            break; //Break inner loop
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the "correct" answer depends on the problem you're solving. If you can, breaking it into smaller pieces is the preferred route. Something along this model:

```
object MainLoop ()
{
    object result = null;
    for(int y = 0; y < 100; y+=10)
    {
        result = SubLoop(y);
        if (result != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

object SubLoop (int y)
{
    object result = null;
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x += 10)
    {
        if(x == 56)
        {
            result = objectInstance;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In my opinion, it's ugly to varying degrees to have multiple return statements from a single function, use extra flags, or (*shudder*) use goto's. But, sometimes one of those is necessary.

**Edit:** This is demonstrating using this method to return a useful object of some kind, you would have "Customer" or "IDataAccess" or "bool" or something other than "object" as the return types if using this for real.

Answer (score 0):

I used LINQ to gather the interesting objects first then performed the operations on the results of the LINQ query. Thereby removing nested loops and replacing with one loop.