# How can I continue The upper Loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, loops, foreach, while-loop

I have this code:

```
foreach(int i in Directions)
        {
            if (IsDowner(i))
            {
                while (IsDowner(i))
                {
                    continue;
                    //if (i >= Directions.Count)
                    //{
                    //    break;
                    //}
                }

                //if (i >= Directions.Count)
                //{
                //    break;
                //}

                if (IsForward(i))
                {

                        continue;
                        //if (i >= Directions.Count)
                        //{
                        //    break;
                        //}

                    //check = true;
                }

                //if (i >= Directions.Count)
                //{
                //    break;
                //}

                if (IsUpper(i))
                {
                        //if (i >= Directions.Count)
                        //{
                        //    break;
                        //}
                    num++;
                    //check = false;
                }

                //if (check)
                //{
                //    num++;
                //}
            }
        }
```

but I want to have `continue` for `foreach` in `while` loop. how can I do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497247/break-nested-loops

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could `break` out of the `while` loop and move on to the next iteration of the outer `foreach` loop which will start a new `while` loop:

```
foreach(int i in Directions)
{
    while (IsDowner(i))
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

If you had some other code after the `while` loop that you don't want to be executed in this case you could use a boolean variable which will be set before breaking out of the `while` loop so that this code doesn't execute and automatically jump on the next iteration of the `forach` loop:

```
foreach(int i in Directions)
{
    bool broken = false;
    while (IsDowner(i))
    {
        // if some condition =>
        broken = true;
        break;
    }

    if (broken) 
    {
        // we have broken out of the inner while loop
        // and we don't want to execute the code afterwards
        // so we are continuing on the next iteration of the
        // outer foreach loop
        continue;
    }

    // execute some other code
}
```

Comment: but I have another codes after while loop and I want to have them and with next foreach variable(i).

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee, you could use a boolean variable.

Comment: question edited. but with your way there is many Nested if in my code

Comment: instead using `if(!broken) {...}` you can use `if(broken) continue;`

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee, you cannot `continue` the outer loop from an inner loop. You will first need to break out of the inner loop. Also as  Piotr Auguscik suggested you could invert the condition. I have updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot continue an outer loop from an inner one.
You have two options:

1. The bad one: set a boolean flag before breaking the inner loop, then check this flag and continue if it is set.
2. The good one: simply refactor your big spagetti code into a set of functions so you do not have inner loops.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, using *goto* is justifiable within complex nested loops (whether or not you should avoid using complex nested loops is a different question).

You could do this:

```
foreach(int i in Directions)
{
    while (IsDowner(i))
    {
        goto continueMainLoop;
    }
    //There be code here
continueMainLoop:
}
```

Just be careful if other people have to deal with the code, make sure they're not goto-phobic.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use predicates for the inner for loop like:

```
    foreach (item it in firstList)
     {
        if (2ndList.Exists(x => it.Name.StartsWith(x))) //use predicate instead of for loop.
            {
                continue;
            } 
     }
```

Hope this helps you.